# How to establish conditions for indexes in pulp constraints

Tags: python, pulp

I am using PuLP in Python-3 to solve a MIP problem.

I want to create a constraint that sums only the variables in which the index i is different from the index j, but I cannot find the right syntax to do it.

```py
for j in Are:
    for t in Per_fl:
        prob += pulp.lpSum([X[i][j][t] for i != j in Are]) <= 1
```

The code above (for i != j in Are) does not work. Is there a way to build this constraint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is with how you are using list comprehension, you need to put the conditional bit last.

There are three indices: `i, j, t`. Given the way you have laid out your for loops I'm assuming your want a constraint for each `j` in `Are` and each `t` in `Per_fl`.

I'm then assuming you want to sum over all of the `i` indexes in `Are`, excluding the one where `i==j`. You would do this as follows:

```
for j in Are:
    for t in Per_fl:
        prob += pulp.lpSum([X[i][j][t] for i in Are if i != j]) <= 1
```